# Postgresql trigger for all tables that include create date

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have 54 tables in my postgresql databse. And most of tables includes date of creation time the data. I want to create a global trigger for all tables which include **CreatedDate** column. And this trigger will update the column when a record inserted.

Comment: Why don't you simply change the columns to `default now()`?

Comment: default now() works fine for sql insert queries. But I use third party softwares like QGIS to insert records to table. In this stuation, new record is creting via forms manually. If I forget fill create date manually, the date field goes NULL to database table.

Comment: Ok. Why don't you try asking on gis.stackexchange.com? There must definitely be a solution to this. I doubt that qgis cannot handle defaults on inserts..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who have some problems with Patrick's solution.
Here the same code with some improvement :

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    t text;
BEGIN
    FOR t IN 
        SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE column_name = 'createddate'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER set_createddate
                        BEFORE INSERT ON %I
                        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_created_date()',
                        t);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: The difference between Gnoocki's answer and Patrick's is 1) Patrick uses defines schema name in the trigger as well the table whereas Gnoocki only defines only the table name and 2)  Gnoocki declares the function as text whereas Patrick defines it as a record. I prefer Patrick's answer.

Comment: Yeah, this would qualify as plagiarism. The etiquette here on SO is that you flag the poster of the answer or correct any mistake in the original answer rather than to present this as something of yourself, despite the opening sentence. It is also not an answer to the question as this only deals with setting the trigger on all existing tables and it does not deal with the trigger function or the trigger itself.

Answer (score 10):

Every table needs its own trigger, but you can use a single trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_created_date() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.createddate := CURRENT_TIME;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For each table you should have a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_createddate
BEFORE INSERT ON <table name>
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_created_date();
```

You can set the trigger for all 54 tables with this code (first create the trigger function):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    t record;
BEGIN
    FOR t IN 
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE column_name = 'createddate'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER set_createddate
                        BEFORE INSERT ON %I.%I
                        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_created_date()',
                        t.table_schema, t.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This obviously assumes that there are no other tables with a column named `createddate`. This you can check easily by querying the `information_schema.columns` table.

Comment: `t.schema_name` should be `t.table_schema`

Comment: @theQuestionMan A belated thank you for spotting the error - corrected just now